# Scan function only read 4 digit of the input

Tags: c, scanf

I am writing a program to get today's day and print out tomorrow's day. However, when I try to get today's date, scanf function seems to read only the first four digits. The the out put is wrong.

for example: if I put 08 19 1995, it read 0 as today.month, 8 as today.day, 19 as today.year

The code is:

```
//Write a function to print out tomorrow's date

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct date today, tomorrow;
    int numberofdays(struct date d);

    //get today's date
    printf("Please enter today's date (mm dd yyyy):");
    scanf("%i%i%i",&today.month, &today.day, &today.year);

    //sytax to find the tomorrow's date
    if(today.day == numberofdays( today))
    {
        if(today.month==12)  //end of the year
        {
            tomorrow.day=1;
            tomorrow.month=1;
            tomorrow.year=today.year+1;
        }
        else    //end of the month
        {
            tomorrow.day=1;
            tomorrow.month=today.month+1;
            tomorrow.year=today.year%100;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        tomorrow.day=today.day+1;
        tomorrow.month=today.month;
        tomorrow.year=today.year;    
    }
    printf("\nTomorrow's date is:");
    printf("%i/%i/%i\n",tomorrow.month,tomorrow.day,tomorrow.year);
    return 0;
}

// A function to find how many days in a month, considering the leap year
int numberofdays( struct date d)
{
    int days;
    bool isleapyear( struct date d);
    int day[12]=
    {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
    if(d.month==2&&isleapyear(d)==true)
    {
        days=29;
        return days;
    }
    else 
    {
        days = day[d.month-1];
        return days;
    }
}

//a fuction to test whether it is a leapyear or not
bool isleapyear( struct date d)
{
    bool flag;
    if(d.year%100==0)
    {
        if(d.year%400==0)
        {
            flag=true;
            return flag;
        }
        else
        {
            flag=false;
            return flag;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(d.year%4==0)
        {
            flag=true;
            return flag;
        }
        else
        {
            flag=false;
            return flag;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `"%i %i %i"` as the format string.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: You're right use  `"%d %d %d"`. `%i` can read octal numbers, so 08 is read as two numbers, 08 is not an good octal one so it is read as 0 then 8.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf() is asking for surprises.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès In reading 3 integers: `"%i%i%i"` is the same as `"%i %i %i"`.  Adding spaces to the format does not make a difference in reading 3 `int`.  Like-wise: ``"%d%d%d"`` will scan like ``"%d %d %d"``.

Comment: Note: Strange to use `%100` in `tomorrow.year=today.year%100;`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `%d %d %d` to scan the input in decimal format,as when you give `%i` format specifier it treats the input from the standard input as of octal format if you specify `0` in front of the number.Be aware!.

EDIT: i would suggest you to read the documentation of `scanf()`.[here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

An important line from this link,about how `scanf()` works with `i` conversion specifier, is:

**Matches an optionally signed integer; the next pointer must be a pointer to int. The integer is read in base 16 if it begins with 0x or 0X, in base 8 if it begins with 0, and in base 10 otherwise. Only characters that correspond to the base are used.**

Comment: `%i` does not treat input as octal.  `%o` treats input as octal. `%i` treats input as decimal, octal, or hexadecimal, depending on the leading `char`.

Comment: I don't have the leading char that indicate whether %i should treats input as decimal or octal. How to use that?

Comment: @silencefox you can use `%d` for that